# Correctly create a display name for attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to create a class that will have attributes which have a display name, i.e,

```py
class MainClass:

  def __init__(self, value):
      self.ip24xs = Attribute(value = value, display_name="Attribute X")
```

This `Attribute` object I thought of implementing like a descriptor, but once I call for example `mc.ip24xs.display_name` I get that the `str` object has no attribute display_name, which makes sense, because it's the return value of the `__get__` method. What is the correct way of implementing such functionality?

```
@dataclass
class Attribute:
    value : Any = None
    display_name : str = "var"


    def __get__(self, obj, objtype = None):
        print(f"Retrieving {self.display_name}")
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print(f"Setting {self.display_name}")
        self.value = val
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code, and I don't get any errors. Only, `ip24xs` is not working as a descriptor but as a regular attribute or `MainClass`, because descriptors work in a different way. This will do, however:

```
@dataclass
class Attribute:
    display_name : str

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype = None):
        print(f"Retrieving {self.display_name}")
        return obj.value

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print(f"Setting {self.display_name}")
        obj.value = val
        

class MainClass:
    ip24xs = Attribute(display_name="Attribute X")
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
```

Note the difference: `value` is a regular attribute of `MainClass`, not of `Attribute`, so you reference it in `__get__()` and `__set__()` by `obj.value`, not `self.value`. You may also want to make it "private" as in `_value` just to make (more or less) sure it is not accessed directly

Comment: But my idea is to have access the display name after in an interface. For example if I want to print to screen `ip24xs` attribute, I want to see "Attribute X"

Comment: I suppose you need to be able to perform at least three operations: getting the display name, getting the value, setting/updating the value. Which syntax would you expect to use for each of those?

Comment: Well, the dot syntax could be useful, like `mc.ip24xs.display_name`. I have no clear mind on that, what do you think?

Comment: If you want to use `mc.ip24xs.display_name` and `mc.ip24xs.value` then you don't need to define a descriptor (and you probably cannot, or at least I can't figure out how to do that): a regular (data) class will do. If you really want a descriptor then the best thing I can think of in this use case is to have the `__get__()` method to return a `namedtuple` of `display_name` and `value`, so you can do something like `d = mc.ip24xs[display_name]` and `v = mc.ip24xs[value]` (while to *set* the value you will still do  `mc.ip24xs = v`). This seems rather ugly, though

Comment: By the way did you already check the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)?